# Tagging the image in our photo album

Tags: java, asp.net, html

Is there any open source photo gallery similar to gallery server pro but which supports tagging images.

Answer (score 0):

Tagging is in the [roadmap](http://www.galleryserverpro.com/blog.aspx?title=Gallery-Server-Pro-Roadmap) for the 3.0 release. I'm afraid I don't know of any alternatives that currently support this.